# Redis listener for oracle DB changes

Tags: database, oracle, redis

I am implementing a Redis cache for data which is stored in an Oracle database.

My question is if there is a mechanism in Redis which can sync DB changes with redis.

i.e, listener which triggers redis everytime a DB change occured, so I can know when to update my cache with relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a mechanism in Oracle (since version 11.1) called [Database Change Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815) to

> " to maintain a data cache as up-to-date as possible" ... "The data cache has to be updated or invalidated when the data changes in the database."

Comment: As far as I know there is no support for using it from Redis, though, so it requires custom development.